# What is the event In Google Chrome API that runs everytime user opens browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I have a  Google chrome plugin that has to sustain a connection (BOSH) with a outside server. That forces plugin to fire `Connect()` every time browser opened. Stumbling through the API can't really find event that would do this once and only once when browser is opened. Is there any or should I go in a freaky way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome loads and runs the scripts of the background pages of installed extensions when the browser is opened.

So if you want to run `Connect()` when the Chrome opens just call it from the background page of your extension.